# Problem when compiling using htlatex and using biblatex-abnt

Tags: htlatex, abnt

I'm trying to create HTML from TeX file. It compiles smoothly with `pdflatex` but when I use `htlatex` the following error shows:

```
Package biblatex Warning: File 'brazilian-abnt-abnt.lbx' not found!
(biblatex)                Ignoring mapping 'brazilian-abnt' -> 'brazilian-abnt-
abnt'.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-abnt/brazilian-abnt.lbx
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-abnt/brazilian-abnt.lbx
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/brazilian.lbx))

! Package biblatex Error: Language 'brazilian' not found.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21 \InheritBibliographyExtras{brazilian}
```

A simple example to reproduce the error follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=abnt,ittitles]{biblatex}
\author{Leonardo}
\begin{document}
Teste
\end{document}
```

Comment: which TeX distribution do you use? It seems like TeX Live from your Linux distro? It is possible that it is quite old. I don't get this error with your sample file, but I remember similar issue that we fixed in the past.

Comment: Running ```htlatex``` it says: ```This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)```.

Comment: I think it is too old. You can try to put this file to the directory with your TeX file: https://gist.github.com/michal-h21/cd5119b93483c453e2a8c81e6bd7b98c I don't know if it suffices though, there may be other issues. Best solution would be to update your TeX distribution, but I think that it means full Linux upgrade :/

Comment: same error... :(

Comment: that's bad. you can find all `.4ht` files here: https://github.com/michal-h21/files/blob/master/tex4ht-4ht-files.zip, in `tex/generic/tex4ht` directory. you can try to put these in a temp directory, and run your sample in that temp directory. I am not sure that it will work though, becase even LaTeX itself changed a lot in the last year. there may be compatibility issues.

Comment: Just don't use them both. use the book class, or whatever. There is no gain in using ABNT rules with `html`, anyway.

Comment: In another ```.tex``` file I was getting the error ```Extra \endcsname. (...) Undefined control sequence.```  After updating the ```.4ht``` files, as suggested by @micha-h21, it did work. Just a ```WARNING``` remaining: ```DOM parsing of file.html failed (...) /texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/figure) [char=47098]```.